# Questions about RTRIM, LTRIM, DATE

Tags: sql, h2

-- question 1

The "rtrim" in the new version 2.1.210 supports one parameter and does not support two parameters, but the previous version 1.4.200 supported two parameters, such as rtrim ('abc123 ',' ABC ')

-- question 2

"Select date '2022-05-12' - date '2022-05-10' as CE from dual" in the new version 2.1.210 will return "interval '2' Day", but "2" was returned in the previous version 1.4.200

Comment: I can't see the question there, you're just stating facts. What are the concrete questions?

Answer (score 1):

We can explain these upcoming changes in H2 database as follows:

> The "rtrim" in the new version 2.1.210 supports one parameter and does not support two parameters, but the previous version 1.4.200 supported two parameters, such as rtrim ('abc123 ',' ABC ')

The previous version of `RTRIM()` allowed you to specify which exact string you wanted to trim from the right side of the input.  Presumably, the new one parameter version will only trim whitespace from the right side of the input.  So doing `RTRIM('Hello  ')` would return just `Hello`, while doing `RTRIM('Hello World')` would return the same input `Hello World`.

> "Select date '2022-05-12' - date '2022-05-10' as CE from dual" in the new version 2.1.210 will return "interval '2' Day", but "2" was returned in the previous version 1.4.200

Previously, subtracting two dates returned an integer/long value of the difference in days.  Moving forward, such date arithmetic will return an `INTERVAL` type.

Comment: H2 SQL database